# 'FlaskDB' object has no attribute 'sequences'

Tags: flask, peewee

I tried peewee with flask for two days, but I failed till now. The code is as the follows:

```
import click
from flask import Flask
from flask.cli import FlaskGroup

from playhouse.flask_utils import FlaskDB

from models import *
from config import config

flask_db = FlaskDB()


def create_app(config_name):
    application = Flask(__name__)
    application.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    flask_db.init_app(application)

    flask_db.connect_db()
    flask_db.database.create_tables([User])
    flask_db.database.close()

    @application.route('/')
    def index():
        return "hello world!"

    return application


def create_cli_app(info):
    return create_app("develop")


@click.group(cls=FlaskGroup, create_app=create_cli_app)
def cli():
    pass


@cli.command()
def initdb():
    flask_db.connect_db()
    flask_db.database.create_tables([User])
    flask_db.database.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

When I run it with the CLI: python manage.py run, I got the following errors:

> (venv) ➜  /Users/yw/Documents/web git:(master) ✗ p manage.py run
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 46, in
>   
>       cli()   File "/Users/yw/Documents/web/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/click/core.py",
>   line 716, in **call**
>       return self.main(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/yw/Documents/web/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/cli.py",
>   line 345, in main
>       return AppGroup.main(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/yw/Documents/web/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/click/core.py",
>   line 696, in main
>       rv = self.invoke(ctx)   File "/Users/yw/Documents/web/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/click/core.py",
>   line 1060, in invoke
>       return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))   File "/Users/yw/Documents/web/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/click/core.py",
>   line 889, in invoke
>       return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)   File "/Users/yw/Documents/web/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/click/core.py",
>   line 534, in invoke
>       return callback(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/yw/Documents/web/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/click/decorators.py",
>   line 64, in new_func
>       return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args[1:], **kwargs)   File "/Users/yw/Documents/web/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/click/core.py",
>   line 534, in invoke
>       return callback(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/yw/Documents/web/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/cli.py",
>   line 388, in run_command
>       app = DispatchingApp(info.load_app, use_eager_loading=eager_loading)   File
>   "/Users/yw/Documents/web/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/cli.py",
>   line 124, in **init**
>       self._load_unlocked()   File "/Users/yw/Documents/web/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/cli.py",
>   line 148, in _load_unlocked
>       self._app = rv = self.loader()   File "/Users/yw/Documents/web/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/cli.py",
>   line 201, in load_app
>       rv = self.create_app(self)   File "manage.py", line 30, in create_cli_app
>       return create_app("develop")   File "manage.py", line 19, in create_app
>       flask_db.database.create_tables([User])   File "/Users/yw/Documents/web/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/peewee.py",
>   line 3765, in create_tables
>       create_model_tables(models, fail_silently=safe)   File "/Users/yw/Documents/web/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/peewee.py",
>   line 5175, in create_model_tables
>       m.create_table(**create_table_kwargs)   File "/Users/yw/Documents/web/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/peewee.py",
>   line 4845, in create_table
>       if db.sequences and pk is not False and pk.sequence: AttributeError: 'FlaskDB' object has no attribute 'sequences'

Indeed, I just want to initiate the DB by using flask.cli tool. As you see, if I use the command “python manage.py initdb”, I can only get the same error output as above.

So what is the meaning of "'FlaskDB' object has no attribute ‘sequences'"? What should I do?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I solved the problem now, please close this post. I made a low level mistake. The problem happened in another file - models.py. In the class definition for those db tables, I should use flask_db.Model instead of Model to be the base class. Just this, now everything is OK.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not strictly a "get free answers to your problems" site. It's a publicly post your problem and have a publicly documented solution. So post the solution as an answer, then it will be "closed".

Comment: Also, please edit the stacktrace so that its readable (it's missing newlines)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `User` model doesn't have correct database.

With FlaskDB, your `User` model should inherit `FlaskDB().Model`
instead of defining `class Meta: database = database`.

```
database = FlaskDB()

class User(database.Model):
    pass
```